# Need a last character

Tags: characters, names

I have this character who is a triplet but I am having a hard time figuring out what the last character of her name should be.
So far her other triplet sisters are named 任子婷 and 任子婧, and I wanted her last character to have a similar meaning to their's. 
(Some of her personality traits, if it helps>>She's smart, respectful and is very leader like.)

Answer (score 1):

congratulation

“婷” & “婧” are both 女部英韻, so, the third one, i would suggest:

婛 (u+5a5b)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=婛](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%A9%9B)

娙 (u+5a19)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=娙](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%A8%99)

婈 (u+5a48)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=婈](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%A9%88)

姈 (u+59c8)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=姈](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%A7%88)

娉 (u+5a09)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=娉](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%A8%89)

have fun :)